# Lowering voltage in a circuit to spin fan more slowly

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

first post here!

[DISCLAIMER] I know little to nothing regarding electrical engineering, I am already in the process of buying a good book to start off, but this issue would need to be solved quickly, hence my question here.

I am in the process of replacing a dead 12V fan with a new one, but the replacement is too powerful (the new fan simply moves too much air for the task). To move less air I decided to lower the fan voltage in order to make it spin more slowly, which I can accomplish with a dc buck converter.

Instead of using a bulky converter, given that I also don't need voltage tuning after I am satisfied with my fan speed, I wanted to go the manual voltage drop route. After some research, I discovered voltage divider circuits, which drop voltages to a desired one thanks to resistors. I tried to drop the voltage to 6V, which I could test with my multimeter, so I connected the fan.

The solution didn't work, and after some more research I stumbled upon [this thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/voltage-divider-not-working-for-fan.875917/) which explains exactly the issue that another guy made with the same task: he didn't account for the fan resistance in the circuit.

Now, since I know very little about electrical circuits, I don't really understand the explanation they gave to him and I don't have the tools to solve my issue alone without burning resistors or messing up my new fan, and would gladly like your help :)

Technical details:

- DC input: 12V
- Old fan: 12V 0.04A
- New fan: 12V 0.08A
- New fan at lower speed: 6-9V

Sorry if I can't provide more details, I really am **this new** to electrical engineering

Comment: @transistor thank you. Looks like I'm new to English as well :P

Comment: Actually, the DC fan motor is a *current-controlled* device; so you can lower its speed by lowering the current. The simplest solution is to connect a (variable) resistor in series. The better solution is to drive it by a constant-current source. The best solution is to drive it by PWM.

Comment: So what is the question? Also, please note that a fan is not a resistor, it will draw a different amount of current at start than when it is running, will draw different amount of current under various conditions, and will not draw a current that is linear with the voltage. As you likely read already, voltage dividers may not be a good idea to power circuits, it would be simpler to just get a suitable fan.

Comment: @Justme My question is how to make that fan spin more slowly, and looking at the comments I basically got too deep into the wrong topic. Not really my best introduction to this community, but that's what happens when you don't know the basics.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist would driving it by pwm be overkill given that I only want a specific speed to be reached?

Comment: I think the humble variable resistor ("rheostat") will do the job... Note that actually there is a voltage divider as you want (the motor acts as the second resistor)... but it is nonlinear...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist has outlined suitable options well. You're not trying to build a complex motor controller to deal with all possible current/speed/torque profiles of the fan. You're just dropping the average voltage across it and it'll very simply settle and run slower. PWM option is best and easier than you think, though only you know your easiness threshold. Search the interweb for '555 pwm board' and you'll see a cheap IC, a transistor, two capacitors, three resistors and a potentiometer. That'll run cool at say 500 Hz and is adjustable. Or just a series resistor will work fine but hot.

Comment: @TonyM, there is another trick - to drop the excess voltage by an incandescent lamp. It will do "three in one" useful jobs - will force (while it is initially cold) the initial current, then will keep it almost constant, and finally, will light.

Comment: The series resistor solution will work if you are not going to derease speed too much, otherwise you can have a trouble the fan does not start. So buy some 100 or 220 ohm potentiometer with sufficient power rating and connect as variable resistor (middle pin connected to one end) and find a point when fan has a reliable start to avoid damage of the device due to no airflow. To find this point the 220 ohm should be better.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist, gets really hot, though, and the probably don't want the light. Resistor will get really hot, too.

Comment: @TonyM, Then we can use the heat... travel hair dryers exploit this idea. Only, there is a [small problem](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_positive_feedback_in_the_travel_hair-dryer).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist, OP has a fan so wants things to get colder, not hotter :-) PWM is the way. Cheap, simple, no-feedback bog standard PWM. A 555 at 500 Hz and a FET at 75% or whatever for the rest of its life and OP forgets it's there.

Comment: @Michal Podmanický, I would do so... as they did in the 19th and 20th centuries...

Comment: @TonyM,  A good story about the ubiquitous resistor that plays many roles... I will tell it tomorrow at the laboratory exercise with my students in Basic Circuitry... at the lecture today we were talking about it... I joked that this was not a lecture but a "story about 1001 resistor applications"- :)

Comment: Looks like this question spawned a comment thread full of ideas! Just to let you know the application, it's not a fan used to cool stuff, but instead move vapor created by one of those essential oil lamps. So there's a "something" (pardon me if I'm too technical) that vaporizes the scented water and the fan just moves the vapors out. The new one is too powerful because the air moved is so much that it creates mist on both the ground and the lamp. Adding to this, the space inside is relatively limited, but a buck converter/pwm controller can be added somewhere

Comment: I already have some buck converters (https://www.amazon.it/Hiletgo-LM2596-DC-DC-converter-1-23-V-30-confezione/dp/B008BHAOQO), pwm speed controllers (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001530885260.html), and the usual bags of resistors, and at this point I would move towards the buck converter if I understood correctly? BTW I reeeeeally appreciate all the help you guys are giving me, thanks a lot!