# Potentiometer sizing

Tags: overheat

I have a 12vdc on automobile trying to install potentiometer for an 7amp cooling fan. I would like to control the the speed. I've purchased a a 2watt 100ohm potentiometer and it's running hot to touch. I was using ohms law to size. Need help please. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you used Ohm's law on 100 ohms ... if you turn the pot to 10% it will have less resistance ... use Ohm's law calculation again with 10 ohms

Comment: A potentiometer is not the right way to control a 7 Amp motor, you should look for a DC motor controller.

Comment: Believe me, you don’t want to purchase a potentiometer which can handle 12 V and 7 A. Search for a PWM speed controller.

Comment: Do your calculations again, assume you want the fan to run on 6 V, calculate the current that will flow (it will be around 3.5 A) so that means 6 V * 3.5 A is dissipated in the fan motor but also in the potmeter. How much is that power? Is it 2 W or more ? (Hint, it is much more) A motor controller is a cheaper and more sensible solution.

Comment: Take a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/557493/lowering-voltage-in-a-circuit-to-spin-fan-more-slowly

Comment: 2W is not nearly enough and you can't even get the rated power from a potentiometer if it's not set to  maximum resistance. You could easily damage the element by exceeding maximum wiper current during start-up. Get a PWM controller like [this](https://i.imgur.com/RoQXPcO.png) for < $10 and add a TVS to protect it in the automotive environment.

Comment: Prior to the age of computers, this is EXACTLY how a cars fan would be controlled.    While not infinitely adjustable potentiometers, you'd have a resistor block with a few options (maybe 3 or 4 resistors so your fan can have 3 or 4 speeds).    Heck, my 2008 Escape has one.    Example: 
   https://www.summitracing.com/parts/smp-ru527?seid=srese1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1b_f4M2l8QIVA47ICh3kVQ2tEAQYASABEgKN-fD_BwE $$$$ Trick is these exist in the blower motors air path, so the motor is cooling the resistor as it's operating.   W/o that, they'd melt.

Answer (score 3):

A 2 W, 100 Ω potentiometer's maximum current can be calculated from \$ P = I^2R \$. Rearranging we get \$ I_{max} = \sqrt {\frac P R}  = \sqrt {\frac 2 {100}} 
 = 0.14 \ \text A\$. This is true no matter where the wiper position is. The resistance wire can only handle 0.14 A.

It should be clear that this is not going to work with a 7 A motor.

Because of this and poor speed regulation we don't use variable resistors to control motor speed. Instead we use some form of pulse width modulation where full power is applied in short pulses to get the required average power.

[image]

*Figure 1. PWM signal transitioning from high pulse width (75%) to low (25%) and back again. Note amplitude remains constant. This will result in a motor speed of roughly 75% and 25% etc. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/dimmable-mains-psu-control/).*

An electronic speed controller (ESC) is what you need.